# How to make the accordion drag & sortable with multiple expanded/opened accordion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

I wanted to make a sortable accordion with multiple opened/expanded accordion item, how to do that?

please help.

https://codesandbox.io/s/draggable-accordion-hgk1gm

expand

Comment: were you able to inplement this?